# Background color alpha value ignored in mPDF?

Tags: html, css, mpdf

mPDF's [supported CSS page](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html) says that the alpha transparency is supported in the background color only, but I'm unable to get the following alpha to work in mPDF v8.0:

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="2" class="nobr" autosize="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td width="5%" align="center" style="vertical-align:baseline;"> <span><b>1.</b></span> </td>
                    <td width="95%" style="padding-top:-0.8%">
                        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                        <meta charset="UTF-8">
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <table class="tgroup cols:2" style="margin-left:1%">
                                        <colgroup>
                                            <col class="colspec align:left colname:col1 colnum:1">
                                            <col class="colspec align:center colname:col2 colnum:2">
                                        </colgroup>
                                        <tbody class="tbody">
                                            <tr class="row">
                                                <td class="entry colname:col1" style="white-space:nowrap;;white-space:nowrap;">Driving Location
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="entry colname:col2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;;white-space:nowrap;;white-space:nowrap;">
                                                    <table width="100%">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;;white-space:nowrap;">
                                                                <p class="text-center">Random modnaR<br>
                                                                    <span style='background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;'>(lorem ipsum dolor)</span>
                                                                </p>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid #1E1E1E;" class="hr"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The text (lorem ipsum dolor) only renders with a black background, even though the alpha is set at 0. It seems that mPDF ignores the alpha value, it stays as black no matter what the alpha value is set to.

Comment: I am assuming that in your real use case, you want to use an alpha value different from 0? because otherwise, you could just try `background-color: transparent`, or `background: none`.

Comment: I don't have control over the HTML content, it is dynamic, so I can't make any changes to it. The problem is that the content contains alpha value 0, and this makes the text render in the PDF with a black background. If mPDF were to honor the alpha value, the background color wouldn't be black.

Comment: Unless mPDF gets this passed by encrypted telepathy, you must have access to it in some form at some point.

Comment: I have access to it, I just can't modify it.

Comment: Why not? Please don’t state stuff like this as if it was actual fact, without giving any explanation.

Comment: It is an actual fact, the application which utilizes this HTML cannot modify it as per business rules. Anyway, the question is regarding why mPDF is ignoring the alpha value. If the HTML could be modified and used in the PDF, I'd have done it and not posted a question here.